# imageMagick is not working on php exec()

Tags: php, imagemagick, exec

```
echo exec("convert ddd.jpg ddd.png");
```

return me Invalid Parameter - ddd.png

it is working if I run it on command line, But for php give me this.
also I have checked phpinfo() there is no imageMagick on Enviroment PATH.
But I have added Enviroment PATH by automatical build in.

any ideas?

I feel the problem is PATH is not shown on phpinfo() Enviroment PATH 
my server is windows server 2008, using IIS , php5.6

```
upodate if I run coonvert.exe only
exec('"c:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.3-Q8\convert.exe"',$output,$return)
```

it will return me same info like in command line.But if I run convert only then give me this.

```
Array ( [0] => Must specify a file system ) 4
```

question solved.....
I restarted my server then look phpinfo()
the c:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.3-Q8 is on the list now.....

sorry I am stupid...

Comment: i don't know exactly but try like this `echo exec('convert "ddd.jpg" "ddd.png"');`

Comment: Invalid Parameter - "ddd.png"

Comment: return me nothing now.

Comment: Where have you installed ImageMagick exactly? What is the full path to `CONVERT.EXE`?

Comment: C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.3-Q8

Comment: You have a space in your path so you need to escape it when you specify the full path, or enclose it in double quotes.

Comment: `exec('"c:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.3-Q8\convert.exe" "ddd.jpg" "ddd.png"');`

Comment: return nothing, I  really feel there is something wrong with  Enviroment PATH

Comment: That error message (`Must specify a filesystem`) means you are running Windows' `convert` and not ImageMagick `convert`. You have not given the full path, or correct path to ImageMagick `convert`.

Comment: I really have no idea now. I have put imageMagick as first path. and tried many solution. still not working

Comment: I removed SOLVED from the title. Accepting an answer automatically marks it as being solved. Either post your own answer, accept the given answer or delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

Windows has its own convert command,
So you need to use full path to imageMagic's one.

Comment: ... or at least ensure that ImageMagick's path comes **before** the Windows one.

Answer (score 0):

Quick Help for skew images and using tesseract ocr:

shell_exec('"C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.8-Q16\convert.exe" C:\inetpub\wwwroot\custom\ocr\js\zzz.jpg -quality 100 -resize 1024x768 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\custom\ocr\js\mynew.png');

shell_exec('"C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.8-Q16\convert.exe" C:\inetpub\wwwroot\custom\ocr\js\mynew.png -gravity North -chop 0x550 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\custom\ocr\js\s3.png');

shell_exec('"C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.8-Q16\convert.exe" C:\inetpub\wwwroot\custom\ocr\js\s3.png -deskew 6% C:\inetpub\wwwroot\custom\ocr\js\s4.png');

shell_exec('"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract" "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\custom\ocr\js\s4.png" output_datas --psm 6');