# PHP exec command not working on ImageMagick

Tags: php, imagemagick, exec, windows-server-2016

I've tried it in those ways:

```
exec('"C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-7.1.0-Q16-HDRI/convert.exe" "ttt.jpg" -fuzz 6% -negate -threshold 0 -negate -format "%[fx:100*mean]" info:', $output, $return_var);
exec('"C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-7.1.0-Q16-HDRI/magick.exe" "ttt.jpg" -fuzz 6% -negate -threshold 0 -negate -format "%[fx:100*mean]" info:', $output, $return_var);
exec('magick "ttt.jpg" -fuzz 6% -negate -threshold 0 -negate -format "%[fx:100*mean]" info:', $output, $return_var);
exec('convert "ttt.jpg" -fuzz 6% -negate -threshold 0 -negate -format "%[fx:100*mean]" info:', $output, $return_var);
```

`$output` returns empty array and `$return_var` returns the int 1

none of them are working and the answers here:

[imageMagick is not working on php exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36569326/imagemagick-is-not-working-on-php-exec)

aren't helping

It works when I run it in cmd like:

```
"C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-7.1.0-Q16-HDRI/magick.exe" "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/ttt/ttt.jpg" -fuzz 6% -negate -threshold 0 -negate -format "%[fx:100*mean]" info:
```

Comment: What's the value of `$return_var` and `$output`? Does it work if you paste that path in `cmd.exe`? Have you tried to use backslashes instead (`C:\Prog...` or even `C:\\Prog...`)?

Comment: I added it to the question, please check it out @nitrin0

Comment: Should I install ImageMagick into plesk folder or something?

Comment: Be sure you have ImageMagick and what version and where it is located. Then do the equivalent of `convert -version` if ImageMagick 6 or `magick -version` if ImageMagick 7 in the exec() command. Tell us what you get.

Comment: I have the latest version. And yeah the location is correct because I tested in cmd and it works