# ImageMagick exec commands to reduce noise on white background to PHP Imagick

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I need this line:

```
magick "input.jpg" -fuzz 4% -transparent white -background white -alpha remove -alpha off -quality 85% "result.jpg"
```

to PHP imagick:

```
$img = new Imagick($root . '/testall/imagemagick/input.jpg');
// ???
$img->setImageFormat('jpg');
$img->setImageCompressionQuality(85);
$img->writeImage($root . '/testall/imagemagick/result.jpg');
```

and I can't find `fuzz` in https://www.php.net/manual/de/book.imagick.php to even start with.

Please help

Comment: Perhaps you should post an example input. Often with JPG, you need a fuzz value of 15%.

Comment: You could try the equivalent of `magick input.jpg -fuzz 15% -fill white -opaque white -quality 85% result.jpg`

Comment: Is it dark spots on the white or just variations in the white brightness? If the former then what you are trying won't work and you would need other approaches. If it is the latter, then what I suggested above might help.

Comment: But I need it as PHP extension because: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69495321/php-exec-command-not-working-on-imagemagick @fmw42

Comment: Did you answer my comments about Imagemagick at that link? You did not answer my last question here either nor provide and example image!

Comment: I did answer 21 hours ago, just look! What you suggested will not help because I need it as Imagick extension for PHP, it's stated clearly in the question. The background is almost completely white, parts can be slightly light gray and there is often noise/sparkles on the background

Comment: You should be able to convert my command into Imagick. Just look at the documentation for Imagick and look for similar names. Sorry, I could give an outline of the commands, but I am not Imagick programmer.  Also that command and your command will only change near white to white. It will not change dark spots that are outside the range of the fuzz value from white.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use: [Imagick::transparentPaintImage](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.transparentpaintimage.php):

```
$img = new Imagick($root . '/testall/imagemagick/input.jpg');
$fuzz = 4 * \Imagick::getQuantum(); // Copied from the example?
$img->transparentPaintImage('white', 0, $fuzz, false);
...
```

Comment: Just tried it, it doesn't remove the noise on white background

Comment: The background isn't perfect white though, partly very slightly gray, these are low quality images on which I try to whitening the background and remove the noise

Comment: Ok I got it, you need to $img->setImageFormat('png'); before transparentPaintImage, then the only thing missing it painting from transparent to white, please update the code including the back to white part and I'll accept :)

Answer (score 0):

Well I tried around with andlrc answer and this is the working result:

```
$img = new Imagick('input.jpg');
$fuzz = Imagick::getQuantum() * ($whitePercentage / 100);
$BackgroundColor = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";
$img->setImageFormat('png');
$img->transparentPaintImage($BackgroundColor, 0, $fuzz, false);
$img->setimagebackgroundcolor('white');
$img = $img->mergeImageLayers( imagick::LAYERMETHOD_FLATTEN );
$img->setImageFormat('jpg');
$img->setImageCompressionQuality($qualy);
$img->writeImage($root . '/testall/imagemagick/result.jpg');
```